# How to bind each GridViewColumn to a separate ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, listview

Firstly I am using this for the `ListView` control itself:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding AllEffects}"
```

So would this not allow individual binding per `GridViewColumn`?

Besides `AllEffects` I have 2 other `ObservableCollection` I want to bind to 2 other `GridViewColumn`:

```
public ObservableCollection<GPUSupportNode> GPUSupport { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<CPUSupportNode> CPUSupport { get; set; }

public class CPUSupportNode
{
    public bool IsSupported {get;set;}
}
```

I am trying to hook these 2 `GridViewColumns` to `GPUSupport/CPUSupport` `.IsSupported` respectively.

Right now I have:

```
<GridViewColumn
    Width="Auto"
    Header="GPU">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox
                Margin="0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                IsChecked="{Binding GPUSupport, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

But it doesn't work. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try creating a ViewModel class like this

```
public class MyViewModel
{

 public ObservableCollection<GPUSupportNode> GPUSupport { get; set; }
 public ObservableCollection<CPUSupportNode> CPUSupport { get; set; }
 public ObservableCollection<TypeOfEffects> AllEffects{ get; set; }

}
```

and create an instance of MyViewModel, say ViewModel and initialize it to your Observable Collections. Set ItemsSource

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel}"
```

and then this should work.

```
<GridViewColumn
    Width="Auto"
    Header="GPU">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox
                Margin="0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                IsChecked="{Binding GPUSupport, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's the only way? It seems like a hack trying to combine all the ObservableCollections.

Comment: MVVM is a standard pattern for enabling Databinding scenerios in WPF and decoupling the view code from the model. It enables an easy way to test all the way up to your GUI, without having the GUI. Here's a great series of blogs on MVVM from a SO contributor: http://houseofbilz.com/archives/2009/05/22/adventures-in-mvvm-model-view-viewmodel/